# Двойная сортировка. Python

Tags: python

Как остортировать список сначала по длине символов, а потом в алфавитном порядке из которых состоит элемент. Так же этот алгорит должен работать на  большем кол-ве элементов и большей длины.

```
a = [ss, n, ooo, a, ff ,vvv, e, tt, f]
result = [a, e, f, n, ff, ss, tt, ooo, vvv]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = ['ss', 'n', 'ooo', 'a', 'ff', 'vvv', 'e', 'tt', 'f']
print(sorted(a, key=lambda l: (len(l), l))) #['a', 'e', 'f', 'n', 'ff', 'ss', 'tt', 'ooo', 'vvv']
```